# remove first char of a variable with jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, char, character

I'm trying to modify a jQuery variable from e.g. **/images/tree.jpg** to **images/tree.jpg** (without the first slash, so it should be a relative path instead of an absolute).

I get the URL like this:
 *var href = jQuery("img.thumbnail").attr("href");*

Now I need this URL on another place, but without the first char.

Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 23):

```
var href = jQuery('img.thumbnail').attr('href');  // e.g.  '#foo'
var secondCharacterAndOnward = href.substring(1); // e.g.  'foo'
```

[String.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Though I'm not sure why an image tag has a `href` attribute, to be quite honest...

Comment: jep, should be jQuery('a.thumbnail') :) thx a lot, substring works

Answer (score 6):

Use the javascript substring method.

```
var href = jQuery("img.Thumbnail").attr("href");
    href = href.substring(1);
```